# Google-app-engine datastore multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a class that runs as a cron job (every 5 minutes or so) and it produces a multidimensional array. I then want to access this array from another class.

Is it possible to just put() a whole md-array as a single object into the datastore? And then to get() that md-array in another class?

If so, is it similar to just putting other simple variables into the datastore?

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot directly store a multi-dimensional array as a property of a datastore entity. <s>The closest type would be a `ListProperty`, but this will only store one dimension.</s> (*Python only, not for Java*)

Depending on what the data in your md-array represents, you could:

- Serialize the values into a byte array, which you store as a `Blob` (1 MB size limit)
- Flatten the array and store each dimension as an individual property
- Create an entity for the rows, and properties for the columns (if 2-dimensional)

For all supported datastore property types, see [this section of the GAE documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types)

Comment: Ahh fantastic just what I was looking for

Comment: The array contains both strings and integers (although I am unsure If I converted the integers to strings before I put them in - currently at a different computer). Yes it is two dimensional currently, so that is another option. I will try your first suggestion incase I move into  N-dimensional (N>2) arrays in the future.